# ONE::Timer doesn't call the subroutine

Tags: perl

I am having a problem with a project I develop at work. It is a multi-threaded application. I use Moose for the Object Oriented Programming and ONE::Timer for the timer. I think I am not using it well as my subroutine is never called. Basically, here is my code:

```
sub add {
    my ($self, $bot) = @_;
    my $provision_object = $bot->provision->new;
    $provision_object->compute;
}
```

and my compute method looks like the following:

```
sub compute {
    <A couple of line code...>
    ONE::Timer->at($time1, sub { <computations1> });
    ONE::Timer->at($time2, sub { <computations2> });
}
```

`time1` and `time2` contains a timestamp. As my script is a server (so it never finishes), I am sure that these times are reached before the end of the script. 
The two subroutine called after `time1` and `time2` seconds are never called. In the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/ONE%3a%3aTimer#our-method-at-Rat-epochtime-CodeRef-on_timeout-returns-ONE%3a%3aTimer) of the `ONE::Timer->at` method, it says:

> If you store the return value, it acts as a guard-- if it's destoryed then the timer is canceled.

That's why I do not store the return value of my call to the method. Am I missing something here?

Thanks a lot for any answers ;)

Comment: What's in `$time1` and `$time2`? Are you sure that time is reached before your script ends for some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, ONE is an event loop*, so you have to enter the loop at some point.  Normally you'd enter you event loop by calling `ONE->loop()`.

The call to `ONE->loop()` won't return until one of your event listeners calls `ONE->stop()`.

One option would be to wrap your code in a collect block, eg:

```
use ONE qw( Collect );
collect {
    # The main body of your program
};
```

Collect will only return after all of your events have fired once.

If you want green-threads, that is, if you want your event listeners to effectively run asynchronously without further intervention, write your program thusly:

```
use EV; # Optional, but everything is better with it
use Coro;
use ONE;

async {
    # Put the body of your program here
    # In order for Coro to trigger and execute your 
    # event handlers, you'd need to be blocking on 
    # IO somewhere in here.

    ONE->stop(); # Call when you want your program to exit
};

ONE->loop();
```

Coro has its own caveats however, and you should read up on it before jumping in.

With the version on Github, this would be the equivalent

```
use EV;
use Coro;
use ONE;

ONE->loop(sub {
    # Your main body
    ONE->stop;
});
```

* ONE is a wrapper around AnyEvent, it does not implement an event loop itself, rather it, provides a platform for adding a mostly thin abstraction around AnyEvent.

Comment: I tried on a simple script to execute `ONE::Timer->at( time()+2, sub { say "At!" } ); sleep 3;` and it works like a charm. 
Would you call the ONE->loop in a specific thread not to block the execution of the script?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive answer. Can you explain me why the simple script above works without the use of `ONE->loop` and `ONE->stop`? Thus why do I need it in my case?
I am already using extensively Perl threads in my program. Is it compatible with Coro? 
PS: I am new to Perl and event so I am trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Perl "threads" (i.e. the windows process emulation) are not compatible to Coro. Coro and EV (and most modules by the same author, i.e. me) only ever work in a the main "thread" (and should work fine there), but things will usually not work in other perl "threads".